# Algorithm to find the object with different weight

Tags: algorithm

We are given N objects, out of which exactly one object is of different weight(can be less or more). Also, we are given M comparisons of the following 3 types -

1. Weight(Set A) < Weight(Set B)
2. Weight(Set A) > Weight(Set B)
3. Weight(Set A) = Weight(Set B)

Where Set A and Set B (both have same number of objects) are a list of objects from the initial N objects.

Given M such comparisons, I need to find the object with different weight if possible. Otherwise tell that the given list of M comparisons isn't sufficient to detect the one with different weight.

Can somebody suggest an algorithm for solving this problem?

Comment: Are you getting a list of specific comparisons or you are given a number M which is number of comparisons allowed regardless of their type?

Comment: Do you know if the object is heavier or lighter before hand, or do you only know that it is either heavier or lighter?

Comment: Also, do you have a set of "standard weight" objects that you can draw from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a much simpler algorithm than the proposed ones, because you know that exactly one object has different weight.

Manage two flags for each object to indicate if they are potentially heavier or lighter (so initially they are not set). Iterate through all the given comparisons and set the flags as follows:

1. A < B: Set the lighter flag for all objects in A and the heavier flag for all objects in B.
2. A > B: Set the heavier flag for all objects in A and the lighter flag for all objects in B.
3. A = B: Set both flags for all objects in A and B.

Now you can find the solution with a single iteration over the objects i.e. their flags, but it is a little tricky because of the special case when you just have equalities and exactly one object never appears in any comparison then it has to be the solution:

1. Initialize `solution = null`, `noFlagSolution = null`, `noFlagCount = 0`.
2. Iterate over the objects:

   - If both flags are set: continue.
   - If no flag is set: `noFlagSolution = current`, `noFlagCount++`
   - If one flag is set:

     - If `solution != null`: return `null` (we have more than one candidate).
     - Else: `solution = current`
3. If `solution != null`: return `solution` (in this case we can also tell if the object is heavier or lighter).
4. If `noFlagCount == 1`: return `noFlagSolution` (the special case mentioned above, here we don't know if the only candidate is heavier or lighter).
5. Otherwise there is no unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2N possibilities - object 1 is light, object 1 is heavy, object 2 is light, object 2 is heavy, ..., object N is light, object N is heavy. Simply check the given conditions are compatible with each possibility. If there's just one possibility that's consistent with the weighings (or two possibilities that correspond to object i being light or heavy), then the conditions are sufficient. If there's no consistent possibilities, the conditions are inconsistent. Otherwise, the conditions are insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you know whether the object of different weight is heavier or lighter then you can find it in ceil(log3(N)) comparisons.

The basic approach is to split the objects into three even piles and compare the two piles with the same number of objects. If they are equal then the object is in the 3rd pile. If not then you know which of the two piles compared the object is in since you know whether its heavier or lighters. Thus, you can throw out the two piles that don't contain the object of different weight. Since this reduces the number of objects to search through by a factor of three with each comparison, then you will be able to make log3(N) comparisons if N is a power of 3, and if not then you will have to make as many comparisons as the next power of three above N.

If you don't know whether the object of different weight is heavier or lighter than the rest then it takes about log3/2(N) since in the worst case you will only be able to throw out one of the three piles, thus reducing the number of objects by a factor of two thirds.

Comment: You don't now whether it's heavier or lighter.

Comment: Alright then its approximately log(N)/log(3/2) comparisons

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding here. The objective is not to produce the smallest set of weighings that can identify the odd object, the objective is to identify the odd object *given* a fixed set of weighings and their results.